# Parsing JSON data with newlines

Tags: javascript, json, api

I have an exported function that takes in a file path. I'm trying to read data from a `.txt` file that has a bunch of objects with data. They're separated by new lines (no commas or anything).

I need to write a function to manipulate the data in a certain way and the input would be the file path.

This is what I have:

```
module.exports = {
  bot_detection: function(input_file_path) {
    fs.readFile(input_file_path, 'utf-8', function(err, data){
       if (err) { throw err };
       console.log(data);
    }
  }
}
```

Sample data from the `.txt` file:

```
{"timestamp": 1487184625, "user": "Eric", "action": "navigate"}
{"timestamp": 1487184655, "user": "Bill", "action": "browse"}
{"timestamp": 1487184685, "user": "Eric", "action": "key press"}
{"timestamp": 1487184715, "user": "John", "action": "idle"}
{"timestamp": 1487184755, "user": "Tran", "action": "search"}
{"timestamp": 1487098049, "user": "Tran", "action": "click"}
{"timestamp": 1487098079, "user": "Eric", "action": "click"}
{"timestamp": 1487098109, "user": "Tran", "action": "click"}
{"timestamp": 1487098139, "user": "Bill", "action": "navigate"}
```

This manages to return the data, but I'm not sure how to create an array holding each object. I tried creating an array outside the scope of reading a file and pushing `data` into the array but that didn't work. Any suggestions? `parse.JSON(data)` only works on the first line for some reason.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data please?

Comment: It'd be better in the question, so you can format it.

Comment: Added it to the question!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the data is not valid JSON encoded. There are no commas to seperate the objects and no surrounding array. This is valid JSON

```
[ 
{"timestamp": 1487184625, "user": "Eric", "action": "navigate"},
{"timestamp": 1487184655, "user": "Bill", "action": "browse"},
{"timestamp": 1487184685, "user": "Eric", "action": "key press"},
{"timestamp": 1487184715, "user": "John", "action": "idle"},
{"timestamp": 1487184755, "user": "Tran", "action": "search"},
{"timestamp": 1487098049, "user": "Tran", "action": "click"},
{"timestamp": 1487098079, "user": "Eric", "action": "click"},
{"timestamp": 1487098109, "user": "Tran", "action": "click"},
{"timestamp": 1487098139, "user": "Bill", "action": "navigate"}
]
```

to archive this you can (and should) alter the source to deliver valid json or on the fly with

```
data = "[" + data.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ',').slice(0, -1) + "]";
```

Edit (alternativ) (inspired from @kshetline's answer):

```
data = "[" + data.split("\n").join(",") + "]";
```

Comment: Thaaaank you, this worked. I have one other last question. Since `fileSync` is asynchronous I can't really define a variable and re-assign it to the JSON data when reading the file. Is there a way I can do this so I can just create a variable holding the parsed data? Or do I need to use `fd.readFileSync`?

Comment: when this worked accept the answer and ask the new question as new question because other users can't find mixed up multiple questions in one question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data is one valid JSON object per line, separated by newlines, no blank lines, this would work (updated with improvement suggested by Occam's Razor):

```
var objArray = data.split('\n').map(JSON.parse);
```

Comment: could have just did `array.map(JSON.parse)` .. really no reason to create an anonymous function that does nothing but call another function.

Comment: Indeed. I wish I'd thought of that. :) I'll edit my answer to take that into account.